# When (and why?) was "or shows lack of research" removed from the downvote tooltip?

Tags: discussion

I think it's a mistake, and the tooltip should again explicitly say "lack of research".

[image: ows]

Funny enough, it's still here on meta:

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [What's the reasoning behind the vote button tooltips having changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349527/168333) on MSE

Comment: @S.L.Barth-ReinstateMonica Thanks. Please don't downvote for "lack of research" 